Proving that $(A-A^T)(A^T-A)\leq 4\Lambda^2 {\rm Id}$ supposing that $A\leq \Lambda {\rm Id}$.
Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ square matrix satisfying that
$$
\lambda {\rm Id}\leq A\leq\Lambda {\rm Id}
$$
for some positive constants $0<\lambda<\Lambda$, where ${\rm Id}$ is the identity matrix. Here, the notation means
$$
\lambda\leq x^T Ax\leq\Lambda,\quad\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\,\|x\|=1.
$$
I want to prove that $(A-A^T)^2\leq 4\Lambda^2 {\rm Id}$.
Notice that $A$ is not symmetric!
Indeed, by the Gelfand's formula, we know $A^2\leq \Lambda^2{\rm Id}$ and $(A^T)^2\leq \Lambda^2{\rm Id}$. So we only need to prove that $A^TA\leq \Lambda^2{\rm Id}$. If $A^T$ and $A$ commutes, this is a direct result of the Gelfand's formula. However, in the setting, we do not know whether these two matrices are commute. To the best of my knowledge, there is no upper bound for the maximal eigenvalue of $A^TA$. How do I proceed?
Any help will be appreciate a lot! Thanks!

Do you know the subordinate norm? it is sub-multiplicative. You could reason with the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (it might work)

Isn’t that obvious? Note that $(A-A^T)^2$ is a symmetric negative semidefinite matrix.

The inequality in the title is different from the one inside the post.
